# If I were not holding my pee, I think I might sleep

Tags: conditionals

> If I were not holding my pee, I think I definitely slept.

Is this correct grammar when I walk out of the movie theater and talk to my friends?

### Update

I was trying to say that the movie is really boring and make me feel asleep. The only thing makes me awake is I was holding my pee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving aside the question of "pee" vs "restroom" vs "urine" the form is incorrect. It could be:

> If I were not holding my pee, I think I would have fallen asleep.

or, a bit less naturally

> If I were not holding my pee, I think I would have slept.
>
> ... I think I definitely slept.

is not correct after "if i were not"

"I think I definitely slept" means that the speaker believes that s/he actually did sleep, not that he would have slept had things been different.

And "I think I definitely ... " is a bit off. "I think" implies doubt, while "definitely" implies lack of doubt. It could be used validly, but is not usual.

Answer (score -1):

What I think you are trying to say is "If I did not have to use the restroom, I would have fallen asleep".

Comment: That depends which country you are in: "Restroom" is American and is not in general British use. I can't speak for other English-speaking countries.

Comment: I marked this down not for the reason suggested by @TrevorD but because it takes a perfectly straightforward statement about wanting to pee, and euphemizes it.

Comment: Pee is a border line crass/vulgar term. That is not how most people would discuss this topic in polite company.

Comment: Among friends who might go to the cinema with you (as in the question) it would be fairly normal, though other informal terms would probably be more common. "Pee" would generally be acceptable from a child unlike many of the alternatives ("piss" for example). This is true in British English and [our health service is starting to recommend "pee" and similar words for bodily functions instead of more traditionally medical language](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/shortcuts/2019/mar/19/why-nhs-wants-patients-to-poo-pee-be-sick).

Comment: @SciFiGuy The Oxford English Dictionary notes that "pee" is colloquial, not vulgar. The Macquarie Dictionary of Australian English records the same: colloquial, not vulgar.

Comment: Actually, I am not trying to ask anything about pee lol

Comment: Pee is not vulgar at all. It's informal. And among friends, "use the restroom" (or toilet or whatever) sounds stilted to me. In fact, most men would say take a piss, let's be honest. And most women would say pee or even piss among friends. The Brits (esp. women) love: to have a wee...:), which is really cute, I think.

Comment: It seems to me that at the very least that "pee" is unsophisticated. The proper and appropriate use of slang is a certainly part of learning English, but it stands to reason that you would start with teaching somebody how to say "I need to go." in the common and conventional manner.

Comment: “Use the restroom” might be more polite with its vagueness, but it might also make people think you had some other reason for using the restroom, and you might not want them to think that. I don’t see anything wrong with using the word “pee”. Use “urinate” if you want to be less informal, but if you already feel comfortable discussing this subject with someone, what’s the point?

Comment: You all are getting carried away with the pee thing, and completely ignoring the "If I were not ...,  I think I definitely slept." thing.

Comment: @Lorel C See my answer.